# UPdate Data property Value based on SPARQL DELETE and INSERT

Tags: sparql, ontology

I have created an ontology, and I want to update some data property in it. I read SPARQL Update in [enter link description here](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/) and I found that with SPARQL Update (Insert/Update) I can update RDF triple based on Pellet reasoner. but I'm in doubt that it is useful fo data property.

For example I have a person class with datapropery has-age "30" and has-age-category="child" 
I create this SPARQL query and I don't have result.

"DELETE ?person nn:has-category-age 'child'\n"
 "INSERT ?person nn:has-category-age 'adult'\n"
 "WHERE {\n"
 "?person rdf:type nn:person.\n"
 "?person nn:has-age ?age.\n"
 "?person nn:has-category-age ?category.\n"
  "FILTER ((has-category-age='child') && (?has-age='30'))\n"
 "} ";
Thanks a lot

my ontology is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

```
<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Object Properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#has-class -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#has-class">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Person"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Classroom"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#has-time -->

<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#has-time">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Courses"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Time"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Data properties
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#has-age -->

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#has-age">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Person"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#has-category-age -->

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#has-category-age">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Person"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Classes
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Classroom -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Classroom"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Courses -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Courses"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Person -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Person"/>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Time -->

<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Time"/>



<!-- 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Individuals
//
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->




<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Jihed -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Jihed">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Person"/>
    <has-age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">30</has-age>
    <has-category-age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">child</has-category-age>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Joseph -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Joseph">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Person"/>
    <has-age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">10</has-age>
    <has-category-age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">child</has-category-age>
</owl:NamedIndividual>



<!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Ralph -->

<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Ralph">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.semanticweb.org/hp/ontologies/2017/9/untitled-ontology-563#Person"/>
    <has-age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer">25</has-age>
    <has-category-age rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">adult</has-category-age>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Formatting of your question always helps other to read the question.
2. Which triple store /SPARQL engine do you use?
3. Without seeing the data, how can we check whether the `WHERE` part is correct and matches some data?
4. Debugging of SPARQL Update queries is obviously possible by first checking whether the WHERE part matches any result - this can indeed be done by using a `SELECT` query.

From your SPARQL query I can see obvious errors in the `WHERE` part:

```
WHERE {
 ?person rdf:type nn:person .
 ?person nn:has-age ?ag .
 ?person nn:has-category-age ?categry .
 FILTER ((has-category-age='child') && (?has-age='30'))
}
```

1. Triple pattern `?person nn:has-category-age ?categry .` and the FILTER is `(has-category-age='child')`. Why? You have to filter based on the variable value, not using the predicate again
2. Triple pattern `?person nn:has-age ?ag .` and the FILTER is `(?has-age='30')`. The same problem as before...in addition, if the datatype of the age is `xsd:integer`, you can't use `'30'`, because inside quotes it would be a string. Either use `30` or `"30"^^xsd:integer`
3. Please please check your variable names next time, it's horrible to see typos there. `?ag` -> `?age` and `?categry` -> `?category`

Fixed `WHERE` part (I'm assuming the age is an integer value):

```
 WHERE {
     ?person rdf:type nn:person .
     ?person nn:has-age ?age .
     ?person nn:has-category-age ?category .
     FILTER ((?category='child') && (?age=30))
 }
```